# DH Parameters of a 2 DOF RP Robot

Tags: dh-parameters, joint, robot-model

[image]

How can I determine the DH parameters of the robot shown in the figure ? As i know, the z axis should show the rotation axis for rotary joints and direction of extension for prismatic joints, so the x0 axis and z1 axis overlap. When I try to obtain a robot model with DH parameters I obtain the following model on MATLAB. I don't know how can I obtain model where the prismatic joint extends on the x0 axis.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the DH convention in Robot Modeling and Control by Spong, the DH table is

[image]

$$
T_2^0 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
c_{\theta_1} & 0 & -s_{\theta_1} & 0 \\
s_{\theta_1} & 0 & c_{\theta_1} & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1+d_1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$